# d3 : Triggering clicked function using hyperlink anchor <a>

Tags: d3.js, hyperlink, anchor

I have a modal that is listing the linked nodes for a given node in a force directed diagram (network).

The idea is that when you click a hyperlink for a connected node, that node will then be selected and the modal will update with the content for that node.

I have a clicked function attached to the nodes, so when you click on a node it is "active," meaning the zoom refocuses on that node, the modal opens and the node has an extra stroke around it.

- I'm using files locally and all data is in a single JSON file.

[image]

(Working example >> https://codepen.io/sgarnea/pen/abPxpKW // only Publication nodes (yellow) have hyperlinks)

**Node code**

```
 const node = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
 .selectAll("g")
 .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("id", d => d)

 node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", R)
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group);})  
  .attr("data-id", function(e){
    return e.id;
  })
  .attr("data-type", function(e){
    return e.category;
  })
  .on("click", clicked)
```

***Note: The script to generate the modal is within the clicked function, as well as the code to create the innerHTML to create the hyperlinks for the linked nodes***

I have tried two approaches:

1. ***Using a relative URL for the href*** : using the text (nodeID) for the hyperlink as the basis for the relative URL (http://www.12345.com/#nodeID. I was not surprised that this didn't work automatically but I dont know what extra step is required to trigger the clicked state for the hyperlinked node.

```
 function primaryAuth (authorPrimary) {
      authorLink += "<a class='modal-AuthorPrimary' id='" + authorPrimary + "' href='/#" + authorPrimary + "'>" + authorPrimary + "</a>" + ", ";
 }
```

2. ***Adding an "onclick=" attribute to the anchor:*** trying to trigger a new function with the text for the hyperlink (node ID) as the input for the parameter. The function attempts to compare this input with the nodeIDs available and if it is true, then to trigger an active state (clicked) for that node.

This second approach isn't working because I know I am not putting in a valid input for the function parameter (the nodeIDs use the names of the nodes as the ideas and they have spaces). I also know that I am not properly setting up the function.

```
 function primaryAuth (authorPrimary) {
    authorLink += "<a class='modal-AuthorPrimary' id='" + aP + "' href='#null'     onclick='nodeHyperLink(" + authorPrimary + ")'>" + authorPrimary + "</a>" + ", ";
}

function nodeHyperLink (name) {
  var checkID = node.id;
  if (checkID === name) {
    checkID.clicked;
  };
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!